# How to change assoc array values in loop

Tags: php, sql, associative-array

I have this assoc array that comes from a Select, it has only one row and 8 cols.
I want to run through each column value and check if it is empty and if it is change it to "NULL".

```
$res = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I found this somewhere but it does not work.

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    if ($res[ucfirst($key)]=="") {
        $res[ucfirst($key)] = "NULL";
        unset($res[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: use it in `while` loop. - `while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ /*do your things*/ }`

Comment: I want to iterate through columns not rows.

Comment: Why are you checking key for null, shouldn't you be checking the column value.

Comment: I am not sure what this piece does as I said I just found it, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == "") {
        $res[$key] = "NULL";
    }
}
```

or

```
$res = array_map(function ($value) {
    if ($value == "") {
        return "NULL";
    }

    return $value;
}, $res);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

You try like this:

```
function is_not_null($val){
    return !is_null($val);
}
$array = array_filter($array, 'is_not_null');
```

You can easily convert this to check for empty, numbers, string, etc.

Comment: You are using `unset`, which means you want to remove it from the array, right? Why do you want null values in your array?